# How to pull local master into local branch

Tags: git, github

I have a remote `origin/master` and a remote branch `remote_branch`.
I also have local `master` and a local branch `local_branch`. When I try to pull the local `master` into the `local_branch` with `git pull master local_branch` I get this.

```
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However, when I do `git branch` I see this:

```
* loca_branch
  master
```

Why can't I pull from my local `master`?

Comment: You don't pull a branch onto another one, you _merge_ them

Comment: @Frodon Well if I do `git fetch` (in order to do a `git merge` later) it fetches the `origin/master`. I want git to look for the local `master` though...

Comment: @Frodon is right, your question is not clear, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @Stophface then you probably want to _merge_ `origin/master` onto `local_branch`: `git fetch && git merge origin/master local_branch`. The `pull` command is a shortcut for `fetch` then `merge`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

merge changes from local_branch **TO** master

```
git checkout master
git merge local_branch
```

merge changes from master **TO** local_branch

```
git checkout local_branch
git merge master
```

Pull is when you have an 'origin' repo :)

Comment: This a merge, not a pull. It is different.

Answer (score 11):

`git pull` is an alias for `git fetch && git merge` you cannot fetch from local branches (only from remotes) - actually you don't need to, if your intention is to merge `master` into `local_branch`, just use `git merge master` when you are on `local_branch`.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that `push` and `pull` is only for remote stuff

Comment: I will accept the answere below because he/she wrote first and answered my question as well. Sorry :-/ And for doing that, I need another minute so says.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, `master` is not a repository it knows of. This is because with `git pull master local_branch` you say "Fetch the branch `local_branch` from remote repository `master` and merge it into my currently checked-out branch".

But that is not what you are after. You want to say "Merge my local branch `master` into my local branch `local_branch`, checking it out if it is not already" and that would be `git checkout local_branch && git merge master`